# removing duplicate entries from multi-d array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2-d array

```
 xx=[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]
```

Now I'm trying to remove duplicate entries from it. For simple 1-D array, simple code like

```
xx=list(set(xx))
```

would work. But trying set on 2-d elements gives an error

```
temp = set(xx)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

One workaround would be to serialize xx elements, and then do a list(set()) on new array and then unserialize all the elements back again.

Is there any solution in python?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Convert elements to tuple and then use `set`.

```
>>> xx=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['c',3]]
>>> set(tuple(element) for element in xx)
set([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>>
```

Tuples, unlike lists, can be hashed. Hence. And once you are done, convert the elements back to list. Putting everything together:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in set(tuple(element) for element in xx)]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Comment: somehow the code failed to remove the duplicate entries. set() is not able to detect duplicate tuples?

Comment: @Neo: This gets interesting. Can you post some sample values?

Comment: string and number of same value or nearly same floating point numbers maybe?

Comment: Breaking your code into "for" loop did the trick. 
    for i in range(len(celeInfo)):
        celeInfo[i] = tuple(celeInfo[i])

    celeInfo = list(set(celeInfo)). Pardon me for I'm new to scripting, is something missing from your code.

Comment: btw, How does one format code in comments? my previous comment looks ugly :P

Comment: @Neo: (1) If a loop worked then a List comprehension should also work. I'd like to see `celeInfo` first before guessing what is going wrong. (2) You can use the built in function `enumerate` to go through a list while having access to its index. For instance: `for index, value in enumerate(celeInfo): celeInfo[index] = tuple(value)`.

Comment: @Neo: Put the backquote character "`" around your code (ASCII code 96).

Comment: celeInfo has elements of URL along with a Tag. Sample: [['/abi.htm', 'Abi (8)'], ['/ada.htm', 'Ada (12)']] . Could the problem be because of the leading '/'?

Comment: @Neo: Tested it with the info you gave me and it worked just fine. `xx = [['/abi.htm', 'Abi (8)'], ['/ada.htm', 'Ada (12)'], ['/ada.htm', 'Ada (12)'], ['/ada.htm', 'Ada (12)']]` and then `[list(t) for t in set(tuple(element) for element in xx)]`.

Comment: @Neo: this wouldn't work if `Ada (12)` was the _string representation_ of an object rather than a _string instance_.

Comment: Nope, it is a string instance. 'Ada (12)' is a direct input to the list. So it must be something stupid that I'm doing, I'll figure that out. Thanks a ton Manoj.

Answer (score 3):

One year after the excellent answer of Manoj Govindan, I'm adding my piece of advice:

Floating points numbers are just a pain if you want to compare things...

For instance,

> >>>0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 == 0.1*10
>
> False

That's because your computer can't accurately represent decimal floating points as binary numbers (computers handle binary/base 2 numbers only, not decimals/base 10).

So be really careful when comparing floats!

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, I've left the `a[i][0]` intentionally this way so you can change the member regarding your need.

```
ab= [['2.71.122.116', 'test_sys_-fw.test_sys_.us'],
     ['10.10.100.26', 'test_sys_5k1'],
     [None, 'Azure'],
     [None, 'test-server'],
     ['2.71.122.119', 'asa-5506-fw'],
     ['33.151.18.23', 'netscaler1'],
     ['33.151.18.23', 'netscaler2'],
     ['33.151.18.23', 'Palo Alto'],
     ['33.151.18.23', 'Arbor CP'],
     ['44.221.2.100', 'fw-la5515'],
     ['44.221.2.101', 'fw-la2-5515'],
     ['44.221.2.99', 'NexusLA2'],
     ['44.221.2.103', 'ASALA5510'],
     ['2.71.122.120', 'asa-5506-fw2'],
     ['2.71.122.106', '2928_SW2']]

def deduplicate_by_ip(a):
    """
    Clears Empty ip address records from list
    removes duplicates by
    :param a:
    :return:
    """

    source_ips = []
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i][0] != None:
            if a[i][0] not in source_ips:
                source_ips.append(a[i][0])
                new_list.append(a[i])
    return new_list

list = deduplicate_by_ip(ab)
print("Total items in original list :", len(ab))
print("Total items after deduplication :", len(list))
print("The list", list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order doesn't matter, I believe the most concise way (for code-golf etc.) is to use the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), and [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) with [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and Python 3.5's [additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
x = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["c", 3], ["a", 1]]

*y,=map(list,{*map(tuple,x)})

print(y)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
> ```

[**See it live**](https://repl.it/repls/GivingNarrowComputation)