# How to reduce duplicating data in an array

Tags: python-3.x

What's the easiest and most efficient way to reduce the duplication of data?

I tried to make an algorithm, but it started to get way to complicated.

I do have data kept in an array like this: `[[data, 'country_code',value],[data, 'country_code',value],[data, 'country_code',value],[data, 'country_code',value]]`

For example, I have `[[2019-01-23, "GER", 200],[2019-01-23,"USA",300],[2019-01-23,"GER", 301]].`

And I need:

```
[[2019-01-23,"GER", 501],[2019-01-23,"USA",300]]
```

Comment: you could search for objects that match a certain key and then add to them rather than append the list with another element

Comment: Use a dictionary mapping `(data, country_code)` to the sum of `value`s.

Comment: `import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(data).groupby([1,2]).agg(sum).reset_index().values`

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819348/removing-duplicate-entries-from-multi-d-array-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accumulate with a `defaultdict`, and use a list comprehension to collect results:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for date, code, n in L:
...     d[date, code] += n
...     
>>> [[date, code, n] for [[date, code], n] in d.items()]
[['2019-01-23', 'GER', 501], ['2019-01-23', 'USA', 300]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way to do that is to use a `Counter`, from the `collections` library:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [
...     ['2019-01-23', 'GER', 200],
...     ['2019-01-23', 'USA', 300],
...     ['2019-01-23', 'GER', 301],
... ]
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for date, country_code, count in data:
...     counter[(date, country_code)] += count
...
>>> counter
Counter({('2019-01-23', 'GER'): 501, ('2019-01-23', 'USA'): 300})
>>> output_data = [[date, country_code, count] for (date, country_code), count in counter.items()]
>>> output_data
[['2019-01-23', 'USA', 300], ['2019-01-23', 'GER', 501]]
```