# Delete duplicate items (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this;

```
a=[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08'], ['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]
```

How can I delete duplicates.

```
[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]
```

Comment: Possibly a better dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819348/removing-duplicate-entries-from-multi-d-array-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously if you don't know this Method. I highly recommand you start with this Implementation and get to know how this work and then move on to higher level implementation

```
a=[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08'], ['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]

print(a)
b = []
for l in a:
    if l not in b:
        b.append(l)

print(b)
```

try to play here and get to know how this work because it is a simple Implementation which shows the basics of how the work should get done solving a simple problem like this

Answer (score 2):

If order *is* important (but algorithmic complexity is not):

```
b = []
for x in a:
    if x not in b:
        b.append(x)
```

If the complexity is relevant, here's an O() solution:

```
seen = set()
b = []
for x in a:
    t = tuple(x)
    if t not in seen:
        b.append(x)
        seen.add(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with

```
a=[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08'], ['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]
uniq = []
[uniq.append(x) for x in a if x not in uniq]

uniq
>>[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
a=[['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08'], ['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]

a = set(tuple(a) for a in a)
a = [list(a) for a in a]

print(a)
# output : [['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02'], ['2019', '08']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = [['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08'], ['2019', '08'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '02']]
a=[list(t) for t in set(tuple(element) for element in a)]
print(a)
```

Convert elements to tuples then back to a list

Output:

```
[['2019', '02'], ['2018', '10'], ['2019', '08']]
```